# AngularJS. Compiling is not enough transformation in a template if using SVG elements

Tags: angularjs, templates, svg

I can use user elements.

```
    <div ng-controller="NoteScretchCtrl"><my-element></my-element></div>
```

AngularJS 1.5.8 Code is there:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('NoteScretchCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.linearray = [10,30,40];
})

.directive('myElement', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div class="boxActive"><img width="300"><div class="boxAbsoluteSVG">'+
    '<svg width="600" height="100" class="svg" >'+
      '<line ng-repeat="ngY1 in linearray" x1="0" ng-attr-y1="{{ngY1}}" x2="800" y2="20" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 3;" />'+
      '</svg></div></div>'
  }
});
```

But in "line SVG" elements coming out this HTML-code compiling:

```
    <line ng-repeat="linear in linearray" x1="0" ng-attr-y1="{{linear}}" x2="800" y2="20" style="stroke: black; stroke-width: 3;" class="ng-scope" y1="10"></line>
```

Why the compilation is successful: created attribute y1 = "10"

but not disappeared attributes: **ng-attr-y1 = ""**, {{linear}}, **ng-repeat = "linear in linearray"** and added closed elements '/line'

You can help me with sample code?

Comment: When and where do you define the value of `linearray`?

Comment: $scope.linearray = [10,30,40];

ng-repeat="linear in linearray" ...  is "for each" in array